# React - How to set initial value of input element from redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Basic scenario -

I have an input element for e-mail address. On click of save, the e-mail is saved into the database. When I refresh, I want the saved value from database to show up as the initial value of the input. After that, I want to control the input's value through regular component state.
The problem I am having is setting the initial state value from props.
I thought I can set the state from props in CDU by making a prevProps to currentProps check.

Actual scenario -

The props I am trying to compare is an array of objects. So CDU shallow comparison won't help. How do I go about doing this?

Please note that I am not using or do not want to use any form library as I just have 3 input fields in my applications.
Thanks

Comment: are you unmounting the component and remounting? or is it always rendered? You have to get the data from your database when the component is rendering. You can set the initial state in the constructor if you have the data when rendering the component. You could also wait for the request then update the initial value

Answer (score 0):

You need to get data from the database on the component mount and set the state of your email. Like this below example (I am doing it on edit user) -

```
 componentDidMount() {
  var headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: `Token ${authToken}`
  };
  axios
    .get(`${serverURL}users/${this.props.match.params.id}`, {
      headers: headers
    })
    .then(res => {
      //console.log(res.data);
      let userdetails = res.data;
      this.setState({
        first_name: userdetails.first_name,
        last_name: userdetails.last_name,
        email: userdetails.email,
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am doing this with a library which directly sets the database value in redux. So I need to set initial value of state from redux (mapStateToProps). So I am not looking to set state from axios call in CDM - rather set state from redux value

Comment: Then you need to create an action and dispatch the return value of the ajax call. Set value with the help of reducer. Import this action in component and call in the componentDidMount method.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution for this:
 1. Create local state for email e.g

```
state = {
 email: '';
}
```

2. dispatch the action in componentDidMount which will fetch the data and store it in redux state
3. use `static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)` to get updated values from props (ref. link :https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) like

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  // do things with nextProps.email and prevState.email
  return {
    email: nextProps.someProp, 
  };
}
```

Comment: gDSFP is called on every render. This would reset e-mail back to props value when you try to change it